# Updating osgi bundle from batch file

Tags: osgi, glassfish-3, apache-felix

(I use glassfish 3.1 with felix osgi)
I need to write a batch script that **updates** one of my OSGI bundles.

The most basic idea is to move bundle jar from autodeploy folder, and return it after a few seconds. Is there a "cleaner" way to do it? Can I easily run commands in felix telnet from a batch file?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can also use BundleContext.installBundle method
http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#installBundle(java.lang.String, java.io.InputStream)